"I am a native Londoner." VS "I am an original Londoner."
The Ocracoke Island in US is said to keep its 17th century English, because the islanders have lived there and were isolated from the mainland for centuries. So, some of them were interviewed how they kept their accent, and one said:

You might say I am an original Ocracoker. BBC- How a US island keep its 17th century dialect (see:6:05-6:15)

The word "original" caught my attention, because he didn't say "I am a native Ocracoker."
So, if "original" can replace the word "native", can this be applied to other places such as:
I am an original Parisian / Londoner / Sydneysider.

I would consider an original Londoner to be someone who lived there when it was founded.

@JohnDouma So... someone in the time of Claudius?

There are of course excellent answers to the question as given, but I'd like to throw in a variant. It might be acceptable to describe somebody with (say) a recognisable Cockney accent as "/the/ original Londoner", i.e. a humourous archetype, irrespective of where he came from.

No, "original" can't replace "native" for a person in all contexts. It's used only in the context of distinguishing people who "were there first" from those who "arrived later", for some meaning of "there first" and "arrived later". That's more specific than just saying "native".
Please note that "original ___" and "originally from ___" are also different from each other.  "Originally from" only states where someone used to be, and does not imply the same "X was here first, Y came later" situation as "original ___".

Regarding the 2nd paragraph, "I'm originally from London" (which is coincidentally true for me) is a common way to put it.  "I'm originally a Londoner" is barely OK; "I was originally a Londoner but now..." makes more sense.

And the only reason "I'm an original Londoner" sounds so odd is that no-one can make a claim to be one of the first Londoners.

@MichaelKay there are (unusual  & irrelevant to the question) situations where it might make sense. If a Briton was introducing themselves among a group of Canadians from London, Ontario, it would be understandable to introduce yourself as an original Londoner, in the sense of the original London. If the others were from one of the “New London” in the USA, it might be even more appropriate.

It may be that these people speak a dialect of English where "original" means "native". But whether that's true or not, that is absolutely not standard American or UK English. As @dangetz says, "original" means something very different from "native".

@origimbo Saying "I'm an original Londer" with that intent would be like saying "I'm a new Yorker" to mean you'd recently moved to York. Anyone listening would think you meant you're from New York (although you might be able to express the distinction with proper intonation and cadence).

@MichaelKay: except in a science-fiction story, of course.  Time travelers and/or long-lived entities could have been living there when London was officially founded.  Or historical fiction set in a time when Londoninium was only a decade or two old.

What he or she said is

You might say I  am an original Ocracoker.

[my emphasis]
Modal You might say there can have the practical meaning of "there is a germ of truth in what I am about to say, even though I'm going to use words somewhat outside their usual agreed-upon meaning".   In certain respects you could say I'm an original Ocracoker. The germ  of truth is that the speaker's accent retains many of the features of the speech of the Ocracoker of those earlier times.
The locution often is used when someone says something tongue-in-cheek. For example, we are at the newborns ward in the hospital, where the babies are all born in the past day or so, and a couple of new dads are talking about their babies. One says "My baby was born this morning. How about yours?"  The other replies, "My son was born three days ago. You might say he's the old man of the ward."
